# How can I compile a C++ application with other files in CMAKE?

Tags: c++, file, build

I want to compile my C++ application but I do not want to have external files (specifically my images and also lists). I want to have those files inside of the executable but I do not know how to do this, or at least how to access them.

Comment: The ability to package resources inside executable files is going to be highly tool-dependent. I recommend adding your toolchain and version to the question. Cmake will only become involved right at the end, telling the tool to do the packaging.

Comment: I’ve been learning programming for a while and I am mildly decent but I can say that I do not know what in the world a toolchain is and i could not identify it if I tried…

Comment: Apologies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain

Comment: Uhhh would it be gcc and ld? I run Linux and for command line compiling I really only know gcc/g++ clang/clang++ and ld to link it